# Ошибка: не отвечает pygame

Tags: python, pycharm, ide, pygame, idle

При запуске pygame в среде pycharm, окно pygame не отвечает, но если вставить тот же код в стандартный редактор Python idle, то всё будет работать. Подскажите
возможные действия, чтобы предотвратить проблему.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можешь выложить код или упрощенную версию, на которой воспроизводится? Если нельзя шарить публично можно отправить на pycharm-support@jetbrains.com и попросить у них помощи.